# Clang, detecting -mavx compiler argument on the source code side

Tags: c++, clang, avx

When I use GCC and set the command line argument -mavx, then the compiler will automagically define `__AVX__` in the source code.

This way I can detect if the project is built with AVX instructions and if not fall back to another code path.

Is there a way to do the same thing with Clang?

Thanks,
Christophe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right test is on `__AVX__`, it works just as well with clang as with gcc. It even works with Visual Studio...

Answer (score 2):

The source in llvm/tools/lib/Basic/Targets.cpp:

```
switch (SSELevel) {
....
  case AVX:
    Builder.defineMacro("__AVX__");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

With Visual C++ the define is `_AVX_` not `__AVX__`.

I was actually checking `__AVX__` but I wasn't successful with it. It's possible that I am running into an issue with my project generator (CMake) to properly set the flags to use AVX.

EDIT: Correction it's two underscores, not one, my mistake!
So yes `__AVX__` is working for VC, GCC and Clang. \o/

Thanks!
Christophe